# ASP.NET MVC Linking two Models in Viewmodel to retrieve matched attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Viewmodel comprised of two objects- a User object which inherits from ApplicationUser built on the usual ASP.Net Identityframework and a Placement object.

The two objects are linked via a StudentID string attribute on the Placement object which contains a reference to a StudentID on the ApplicationUser object.

The relevant bits of the two models are:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int CountyID { get; set; }

    public string StudentID { get; set; }
}

public class Placement
{
    public int PlacementID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Student Assigned")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "Not Assigned")]
    public string StudentID { get; set; }
}
```

I have a ViewModel which links both classes as follows:

```
namespace Placementv2.ViewModels
{
    public class PlacementStudentIndexData
    {
        public IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> User { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Placement> Placement { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have an Assign action on the Placement controller which assigns the selected user to the currently active. (this is based on a details view for Placements which shows a single placement and a model which comprises possible unassigned ApplicationUser objects. The action is as follows:

```
public ActionResult Assign(int PlacementID, string StudentID)
{
    Placement placement = db.Placements.Find(PlacementID);
    ApplicationUser student = db.Users.Find(StudentID);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    { 
        placement.Filled = true;
        placement.StudentID = StudentID;

        db.SaveChanges();

        Placement postedplacement = db.Placements.Find(PlacementID);
        var studenttoupdate = db.Users.Where(p => p.StudentID == postedplacement.StudentID);
        studenttoupdate.Single().Placed = true;
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Details", new {ID = placement.PlacementID});
}
```

My issue is that following assignment of a user to a placement my placements Details view (which references the Viewmodel) I can retrieve attributes of both Users and Placements but I am unable to bind the specific user to the placement based on this join on StudentID.

```
<dd>
    @if (Model.Placement.FirstOrDefault().Filled == true)
    {
        <div class="alert-success">
            Assigned to StudentID: @Model.Placement.FirstOrDefault().StudentID

            @Model.User.Where(f => f.StudentID == @Model.Placement.FirstOrDefault().StudentID).First().SecondName
        </div>
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="alert-danger">Not Assigned</div>
    }

    @if (Model.Placement.FirstOrDefault().Filled == true)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Remove Student", "Unassign", "Placements", new { Model.Placement.FirstOrDefault().StudentID, Model.Placement.FirstOrDefault().PlacementID }, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
    }
</dd>
<dt>
```

The **@Model.Placement.FirstOrDefault().StudentID** works fine as it's referencing the Placement object but the  **@Model.User.Where(f => f.StudentID== @Model.Placement.FirstOrDefault().StudentID).First().SecondName** is unable to bind the right User instance to retrieve other User attributes such as SecondName. I've tried various versions of this and experimenting with the available Intellisense options without success.

Comment: In investigating this further, I'm thinking that perhaps the binding of the two models should happen in the Controller and not in the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This eventually worked for me. In summary, I had to create a second collection of users in the controller which was prefiltered to match the current placement id.

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        var viewModel = new PlacementStudentIndexData();
        viewModel.Placement = db.Placements.Where(p => p.PlacementID == id.Value).ToList();
        viewModel.UnplacedUser = db.Users.Where(p => p.Placed == false).Where(p => p.PlacementYearID > 0).ToList();
        viewModel.PlacedUser = db.Users.Where(u => u.StudentID == db.Placements.Where(p => p.PlacementID == id.Value).FirstOrDefault().StudentID);
```